# NSUserDefaults - reload needed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I use NSUserDefaults to store some stuff.

It works fine but only after i restart the app.

I use:
[prefs synchronize];
I thought it would immediately save the data but instead preferences stay null.

If you have any idea or already deal with it let me know.
Thanks for any help.

Wallou

Comment: Please provide the code that writes to the NSUserDefaults. When you use synchronize the changes should be saved. If they are null, it probably means that null was the value written to them.
Try looking in the debugger or NSLog out the value just prior to persisting it. Also make sure you use the correct method: setObject/setBool etc. on the NSUserdefaults object.

Comment: RickiG's comments are good, I just want to ask whether perchance you are using NSUserDefaultsController, because that adds some other ways to get confused.

Comment: hey,

here is my code:

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 
 // saving an NSString

 [prefs setObject:identField.text forKey:@"mail"];

 [prefs setObject:pwdField.text forKey:@"password"];
  
  
 [prefs synchronize];

the values are null until i restart my app. Then they have the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my issue. I was doing the same thing at two different places (old code forgotten somewhere). For information here is my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:identField.text forKey:@"mail"];
[prefs setObject:pwdField.text forKey:@"password"]; 
mail=[prefs objectForKey:@"mail"];
pwd=[prefs objectForKey:@"password"];

//This is to synch prefs
[prefs synchronize];
NSLog(@"pwd: %@, username:%@", mail, pwd);
```